# Clamping and rounding a value during implicit conversion

Tags: c#, struct, implicit-conversion

I've developer a custom integral type. Here it is its definition in C#.

```
public struct PitchClass
{
    private readonly int value;

    private PitchClass(int value)
    {
        this.value = CanonicalModulus.Calculate(value, 12);
    }

    public static implicit operator PitchClass(int value)
    {
        return new PitchClass(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator PitchClass(double value)
    {
        return new PitchClass((int)Math.Round(value));
    }

    public static implicit operator int(PitchClass pitchClass)
    {
        return pitchClass.value;
    }
}
```

The `PitchClass` is an `int` whose values are in the range [0, 11].

As you can read from the C# code both `int` and `double` values can be implicitly converted to `PitchClass` using a *canonical modulus operator*:

```
PitchClass pitchClass = -3;
Console.WriteLine(pitchClass); // 9
```

The `double` value is also rounded during implicit conversion:

```
PitchClass pitchClass = -3.4d;
Console.WriteLine(pitchClass); // 9
```

I couldn't find other examples of custom data types that do so many things to the data type to convert.

Why? Is it bad practice? If so, is there another way to avoid doing argument validation for every PitchClass variable in every method?

Thanks

Comment: No its not bad practice depending on your need, and there are plenty of examples, as to `that do so many things` this is actually very light and you would probably need a lot more boiler plating to make this usable with the many types of operators that you might use. There are many approaches here, however if this type is being used a lot, it might be worth the effort to get this right and add as much as you need

Comment: What about making the conversion from double explicit? The conversion from double to int is also explicit.

Answer (score 2):

It is not bad practice to create a base type and make it convertible to other base data types. Neither is it to define implicit and explicit conversions.

Look at the implementation of [Int32 in the .Net Framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252). This structure implements many interfaces to make it Convertible to other structure types, to format it nicely and a few other stuff.

If you intend on heavily using this structure, implementing IConvertible, IComparable, IEquatable (and the methods GetHashCode() & Equals()) is a good idea, because almost all the native data types do so.

The Complex type is given as example of Custom data type in [the explanation for IConvertible interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=netframework-4.7.2) and they do many different conversions to and from other types.

Also, the explicit conversion from double to int is doing kind of the same thing you do, making this conversion narrowing (may incur data loss).